# Which 1Blocker "Block Comments" rules do I need to disable in order to re-enable Reddit commenting?

Tags: ios, mobile-safari, safari-extensions

I recently updated my blocking rules in 1Blocker (a popular iOS 9 Safari content blocker), and something is now blocking my ability to use [Reddit](https://reddit.com/) normally.

I already figured out that I needed to disable the `Block Comments > Hide .commentarea` rule in order to see the main comment area. However, one or more of the other "Block Comments" rules is blocking the main comments link at the bottom of each Reddit row. Here's an annotated screenshot from desktop Safari showing which link I'm talking about:

[image: 1Blocker Reddit missing comments link]

I've already determined that it must be one or more of the "Block Comments" rules, because if I disable the whole set, that link comes back. I just haven't been able to figure out exactly which of the 169 remaining "Block Comments" rules it is, even after inspecting the HTML and CSS (I'm just a dabbler with HTML & CSS, not an expert).

So, which 1Blocker "Block Comments" rule(s) do I need to disable to re-enable the Reddit comments link?

Answer (score 1):

Given the lack of further communication and clarification, ensure that your device is running iOS 11.2 and have installed 1Blocker 1.4.1, where the stated issue cannot be replicated.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is whitelist Reddit.